# Navigationbar transition animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers and i am using push segue to show them. My storyboard looks like this:

[image]

But i want to use standalone navigation bar on second view controller. To do this i wrote following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    placeNavigationBar()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}


var normalButton: UIButton!
var counter = 0
let item = UINavigationItem()
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
private func placeNavigationBar() {



    let backButtonImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")
    normalButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: backButtonImage!.size.width, height: backButtonImage!.size.height))
    normalButton.setImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal)

    normalButton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
    normalButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
    normalButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    normalButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 3.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -3.0)
    normalButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: normalButton)
    backBarButton.tintColor = .systemBlue


    let leftLabel = UILabel()
    leftLabel.text = "anony-12345678645"
    leftLabel.textColor = .black

    let profilePicture = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    profilePicture.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profilePicture.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "test2")
    profilePicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


    profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true

    profilePicture.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    profilePicture.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = 15


    item.leftBarButtonItems = [backBarButton, UIBarButtonItem(customView: profilePicture) ,UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftLabel)]


    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.barTintColor = .white

    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true



    navigationBar.items = [item]
    navigationBar.delegate = self
}
```

It is working well but i am not happy with the navigation bar transition animation. This video shows how it looks now:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wakUhA940c

What i want:

https://youtu.be/h3-HzKQsxWc

Check the navigation bar transitions on both videos, in second video the navigation bar comes to top of the first view controller's navigation bar. But in the first video the second navigation bar just pushes the first navigation bar to off screen.

How can i achive the same tranisiton in second video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar where the initial controller had a custom navigation bar look-alike, and what I did was to call `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(_, animated: true)` on each controller on their `viewWillAppear` methods, with `true` on the main controller and `false` on the rest.

You could do the same, and add a separate UINavigationBar to your view. If you set its constraints properly (basically pin it to the safeArea.top of your controller), it will expand to the safe area.

You will have to populate the navigation bar by accessing it directly instead of your controller's `navigationItem`, but it's not a big deal and you'll get the transition you want.

If you want this to happen between all the controllers in the stack, just hide the navigation bar on the navigation controller and set a navigation bar on each view yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you don't prefer is actually the default behavior, animation of iOS. Now, one way to do what you do prefer is making your own navigation bar.

You may hide or show (toggle) the visibility of your navigation bar in your `viewWillAppear` method by using the following:

```
/// Shows the navigation bar.
public func showNavBar(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

/// Hides the navigation bar.
public func hideNavBar(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

And then start doing the layout of your navigationBar in Storyboard.

Lastly, making use of **Simulated Metrics**, like selecting **NONE** to **Top Bar** will help you visualize what you're doing.

[image]

Comment: Because i am doing a chat app and on chat screen i want to show unread messages count on the back button. I researched a lot and everybody says it is really hard because back button comes from previous view controller.

Comment: It's doable, shouldn't be that hard. Let's solve this problem first and then post a new one for that particular problem.